# rename all columns in list of data frames

Tags: r, list, purrr

I have a list of dataframes

```
vars <- c("Col_1", "Col_2", "Col_3")

list_df <- list(
  tibble(
    a = 1,
    b = 2,
    c = 3
  ),
  tibble (
    d = 1,
    e = 2,
    f = 3
  )
)
```

And I'd like to rename the columns using the `vars` but I think I'm missing something here.

```
map(list_df, ~rename_all(.x, vars))
```

The result should be:

```
list(
  tibble(
    Col_1 = 1,
    Col_2 = 2,
    Col_3 = 3
  ),
  tibble (
    Col_1 = 1,
    Col_2 = 2,
    Col_3 = 3
  )
)
```

I'd like this to work regardless of the initial column names (and all data frames will always only have three columns. Is this possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We need the `~` inside the `rename_all`

```
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)
map(list_df, ~rename_all(.x, ~ vars))
#[[1]]
# A tibble: 1 x 3
#  Col_1 Col_2 Col_3
#  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#1     1     2     3

#[[2]]
# A tibble: 1 x 3
#  Col_1 Col_2 Col_3
#  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#1     1     2     3
```

---

Or with `set_names/setNames`

```
map(list_df, set_names, vars)
map(list_df, setNames, vars)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a base R solution

```
Map(setNames,list_df,list(vars))
```

which gives

```
> Map(setNames,list_df,list(vars))
[[1]]
# A tibble: 1 x 3
  Col_1 Col_2 Col_3
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     1     2     3

[[2]]
# A tibble: 1 x 3
  Col_1 Col_2 Col_3
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     1     2     3
```